# Multiprocess parent return value

Tags: c, multiprocessing, return, parent-child

Im wondering about the nature of the variable `status` and when its returned in a function.

Ive set my function to get an error, but if I dont do `return status >> 8`(127) and instead do `return status`, I get a return value of 0.

Ive used `return WEXITSTATUS (status)` in the past and itd return the correct status number.

My questions are if `WEXITSTATUS` actually does the operation `status >> 8`?
And when doing Multiprocessing and the parent process exists properly is it better to verify with `WIFEXITED(status)` then return `WEXITSTATUS (status)` rather than doing what I do?

```
int main {
    int status;
    int filedes[2];
    pid_t pid_enfant;
    pipe(filedes);

    if (pid_child == 0) {
        ...
        char *tab[] = {"/bin/bash", "-c", arg[1], NULL};
        execv("/bin/bash", arg[1]);
        return 1;
    } else {
        ...
        pid_t pid_child = wait(&status);
        return status >> 8;                   -- // return this vs this below
        //if (WIFEXITED(status) && pid_valide == pid_child)
              //return WEXITSTATUS (status);
    } 
}
```

Comment: If you look in the header files you'll probably find something like `#define WEXITSTATUS(status)  __WEXITSTATUS (status)` and `#define __WEXITSTATUS(status)  (((status) & 0xff00) >> 8)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your your question regarding `WEXITSTATUS`, the answer is yes; it is meant to shift the status down by 8 bits.

> ```
>    WEXITSTATUS(wstatus)
>          returns the exit status of the child.  This consists of
>          the least significant 8 bits of the status argument that
>          the child specified in a call to exit(3) or _exit(2) or as
>          the argument for a return statement in main().  This macro
>          should be employed only if WIFEXITED returned true.
> ```

Further, it explicitly states that the value of `WEXITSTATUS(wstatus)` is only valid if `WIFEXITED(wstatus)` is non-zero. So for your code to be correct with this specification, you should have

```c
pid_t pid_child = wait(&status);
if (WIFEXITED(status))
{
  return WEXITSTATUS(status);
}
else
{
  // child did not terminate normally
}
```

As to *why* you should check this, here's a toy example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
  int signal = /* choose your favourite signal, or 0 */;
  
  switch (fork())
  {
    case -1:
      perror("fork");
      return -1;
    
    case 0:
      if (signal) { raise(signal); }
      return 0;

    default:
      {
        int status;
        pid_t child = wait(&status);        
        printf("child=%d, status=%04x\n", child, status);
        
        if (WIFEXITED(status))
        {
          puts("good exit");
          return WEXITSTATUS(status);
        }
        else
        {
          puts("bad exit");
          return -1;
        }
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

If we do not raise anything in the child and get a clean exit, we'll see `child=..., status=0000` in the parent, and would take the 'good exit' branch returning 0, as expected. However, if we raise something like `SIGSEGV` in the child, then the parent will get `child=..., status=008b`. Now, if you blindly did `status >> 8`, then your parent would return `0` just like the 'good exit' path, but clearly the child did not exit cleanly.

Comment: IIRC, if child did not terminate normally its verified with  `(WIFSIGNALED(status)`. 
One thing though, I was under the impression wexitstatus also works if the status is 0.

I actually tested it and it seems to be the case. Thanks a lot